# ¿Lectura y escritura de una estructura en binario?

Tags: c

Realizar un programa que permita manejar una entidad definida por ud, con por lo menos 2 campos (uno numérico y otro alfanumérico). Dicho programa deberá trabajar la entidad de manera dinámica, permitiendo guardar en un archivo binario por lo menos dos datos de la entidad en cuestión. Por último leer del archivo dichos datos y mostrarlos.

Decidí crear una persona, con campos de ID y eMail.

```c
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char email[32];
}ePersona;
```

No encuentro forma de guardar y leer el archivo binario, ¿alguién podría darme un ejemplo con esta estructura?

```c
void crearArchivoBin(char* path,ePersona* lista)
{
    FILE* pFile;
    int i;
    ePersona* personaAux;
    if(path!=NULL && lista!=NULL)
    {
        pFile=fopen(path,"wb");

        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            fwrite(lista+i,sizeof(ePersona),1,pFile);
        }
    }

    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Intente con eso pero estoy seguro de que algo debe estar mal, tal vez el sizeof o la lista que paso.

```
int loadBinary(ePersona* lista,char* path)
{
    FILE* pArchivo;
    int ret=0;

    if(lista!=NULL)
    {
        pArchivo=fopen(path,"rb");
        ePersona* newPersonaAux;

            while(!feof(pArchivo))
            {
                newPersonaAux=nuevaPersonaConstructor();
                fread(newPersonaAux,sizeof(ePersona),1,pArchivo);
                ret=1;
            }


    }
        fclose(pArchivo);


    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, ¿Por qué crees que esta mal? ¿Te sale algun error? Dentro de todo parece que esta bien (funciona, pero no verificas lo que devuelve `fopen` ni `fwrite`). Para lo de leerla de un archivo, busca información, trata de hacerlo y si tenes alguna duda específica podés preguntar.

Comment: Mi problema vendría a ser que no puedo saber si estoy guardando correctamente el archivo, intenté leerlo de la siguiente manera
`pArchivo=fopen(path,"rb");
        ePersona* newPersonaAux;

            do
            {
                newPersonaAux=nuevaPersonaConstructor();
                fread(newPersonaAux,sizeof(ePersona),1,pArchivo);
            }while(!feof(pArchivo));
             fclose(pArchivo);`
Pienso que luego del fread debería pasar newPersonaAux a una lista y devolverla(Esto está dentro de una función a la que le paso path y una cadena con el nombre del archivo)

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pone lo que pusiste en el comentario (tambien la función en la que está el codigo) así se ve mejor y puedo responderte.

Comment: Listo, espero se entienda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función nuevaPersonaConstructor debería recibir como parámetro los campos de
la estructura ePersona y devolver un puntero a ePersona o NULL en caso de error.
Una posible implementación es esta:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Crea e inicializa una estructura ePersona con `id` y una copia de email
 * Verifica que email tenga como mucho 31 caracteres.
 * Devuelve un puntero a ePersona o NULL en caso de error.
 *
 */
ePersona *nuevaPersonaConstructor(int id, char *email) {
    if (strlen(email) > 31) {
        return NULL;
    }

    ePersona *nuevaPersona = malloc(sizeof *nuevaPersona);

    if (!nuevaPersona) {
        return NULL;
    }

    nuevaPersona->id = id;
    strcpy(nuevaPersona->email, email);

    return nuevaPersona;
}
```

Podríamos usar tu function `crearArchivoBin` de esta forma:

```
int main() {
    ePersona personas[] = {{1, "persona1@gmail.com"}, {2, "persona2@gmail.com"}};

    crearArchivoBin("salida.bin", personas);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Pero no nos sirve, porque el ejercicio pide que sea de forma dinámica (supongo que
usando `nuevaPersonaConstructor`), asi que tenemos que definir otra función, que
voy a llamar `guardarEnArchivo`. Se usaría de esta forma:

```
int main() {
    int cantidadPersonas = 2;

    /*
     * `nuevaPersonaConstructor` devuelve un puntero a ePersona, así que debemos
     * asignar memoria para `cantidadPersonas` punteros.
     *
     */

    ePersona **personas = malloc(sizeof *personas * cantidadPersonas);

    if (!personas) {
        fputs("No se pudo reservar memoría para `personas`\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadPersonas; ++i) {
        // por simplicidad usamos el mismo nombre
        personas[i] = nuevaPersonaConstructor(i, "Nombre");

        if (!personas[i]) {
            fputs("No se pudo reservar memoría para una persona\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    bool exito = guardarEnArchivo("salida.bin", personas, cantidadPersonas);

    if (!exito) {
        fputs("No se pudo guardar el archivo\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Y está definida así:

```
/*
 * Escribe la `lista` con `cantidadPersonas` elementos en el archivo `path`
 * Devuelve `true` normalmente, si hubo un error `false`
 *
 */
bool guardarEnArchivo(const char *path, ePersona **lista, int cantidadPersonas) {
    if (!path || !lista) {
        return false;
    }

    FILE *salida = fopen(path, "wb");

    if (!salida) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadPersonas; ++i) {
        if (fwrite(lista[i], sizeof **lista, 1, salida) < 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    fclose(salida);

    return true;
}
```

Es parecida a `crearArchivoBin` pero usando los punteros devueltos por
`nuevaPersonaConstructor`.

Si ejecutamos lo que tenemos hasta ahora y abrimos el archivo `salida.bin`
usando xxd (un programa para ver los bytes del archivo en hexadecimal),
obtenemos:

```
$ xxd salida.bin
00000000: 0000 0000 4e6f 6d62 7265 0000 0000 0000  ....Nombre......
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0100 0000 4e6f 6d62 7265 0000  ........Nombre..
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........
```

La primera columna es un *offset* en hexadecimal para ubicarnos en el archivo. La parte
de la derecha es la representación ascii de esos bytes. Las demas columnas tienen cada
una dos bytes del archivo en hexadecimal. En mi computadora los enteros (*int*) tienen
4 bytes y orden [Little-endian](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Eso quiere decir que en memoria los enteros del uno
al diez se representa con los bytes:

```
0100 0000
0200 0000
0300 0000
...
0A00 0000
```

En los bytes del archivo podemos notar que estan los bytes 0000 0000 (el entero 0)
seguido de 32 bytes en los que está incluido la cadena "Nombre" y luego los bytes
0100 0000 (el entero 1) y otros 32 bytes. Por lo que el código funciona correctamente.

Ahora para leer el archivo tenemos que hacer los pasos contrarios. Como no sabemos
la cantidad de personas en el archivo, primero debemos hallarlo. Podemos hacerlo
hallando el tamaño del archivo y dividiendolo por el tamaño de una `ePersona`.
Como es un archivo binario y todos los elementos tienen el mismo tamaño eso
nos daría la cantidad de elementos:

```
/*
 * Devuelve la cantidad de personas en un archivo,
 * en caso de error -1.
 *
 */
long hallarCantidadPersonas(const char *path) {
    FILE *archivo = fopen(path, "rb");

    if (!archivo) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    long offset = ftell(archivo);

    if (offset == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(archivo);

    return (offset + 1) / sizeof(ePersona);
}

/*
 * Lee el archivo `path` y lo pone en `lista`
 * Devuelve `true` normalmente. En caso de error `false`.
 *
 */
bool leerArchivo(const char *path, ePersona ***lista, int *cantidad) {
    long cantidadPersonas = hallarCantidadPersonas(path);

    if (cantidadPersonas == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    *cantidad = cantidadPersonas;

    ePersona **listaAux = malloc(sizeof *listaAux * cantidadPersonas);

    if (!listaAux) {
        return false;
    }

    FILE *entrada = fopen(path, "rb");

    if (!entrada) {
        return false;
    }

    ePersona personaAux;

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadPersonas; ++i) {
        if (fread(&personaAux, sizeof personaAux, 1, entrada) < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        // *personaAux* es temporal, así creamos otra ePersona con los mismos campos

        ePersona *persona = nuevaPersonaConstructor(personaAux.id, personaAux.email);

        if (!persona) {
            return false;
        }

        listaAux[i] = persona;
    }

    *lista = listaAux;

    return true;
}
```

Y se puede usar de la siguiente forma:

```
int main() {
    int cantidadPersonas;
    ePersona **personas;

    if (!leerArchivo("salida.bin", &personas, &cantidadPersonas)) {
        fputs("No se pudo leer `salida.bin`\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!guardarEnArchivo("salida2.bin", personas, cantidadPersonas)) {
        fputs("No se pudo guardar `salida2.bin`\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Luego podemos comprobar que funciona correctamente de tres formas:

- Iteramos las personas con un *for* e imprimimos sus campos.
- Vemos *salida.bin* y *salida2.bin* con *xxd*, y comparamos los bytes (lo que hice).
- Usamos `diff salida.bin salida2.bin` que busca diferencias y no debería
  mostrar nada.

No cerre o libere la memoria de la mayoría de cosas en caso de error para no aumentar
la complejidad, pero deberías hacerlo en tu código.